# Resources won't open at MODx manager

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have two separate MODx installs in two separate servers and have recently seen same issue. When you click on some resources in the MODx manager then new page loads as it should but just blank area in the right main area where should be all the editable areas to edit the content of the resource: http://screencast.com/t/RiQnGZxjd

MODX Revolution 2.4.2

Comment: Look at your console - is there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this you can usually get to the bottom of the issue by:

- disabling JS compression in the System Settings
- opening your browser's inspector and looking in the console for any errors (could be a plugin/Template Variable or Extra that isn't loading)
- re-run the MODX installer as an Update